# Excel-like filtering ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, filter

I'm trying to filter my Listview Excel-like.

What I need:
 - Sorting ascending/descending
 - A direct search function
 - Checkboxes for showing all or just selected ones

These filter options should be shown when I'm clicking on the column header and after selecting the filter method the listview should be updated depending on the clicked filter/sorting method.

Actually I’m able to create a normal Listview and fill it with vales from a struct list

[Template: What I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWljC.jpg)

My XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="lVTable"  SelectionMode="Single" Margin="28,231,32,26" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column1}" Width="120">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content ="Column1"/>
        </GridViewColumn>

        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column2}" Width="120">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content =" Column2"/>
        </GridViewColumn>

        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column3}" Width="220">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content =" Column3"/>
        </GridViewColumn>

        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column4}" Width="220">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content =" Column4"/>
        </GridViewColumn>

        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column5}" Width="220">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content =" Column5"/>
        </GridViewColumn>

        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column6}" Width="220">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content =" Column6"/>
        </GridViewColumn>

        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column7}" Width="220">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content =" Column7"/>
        </GridViewColumn>

    </GridView>
</ListView.View></ListView>
```

My code behind:

```
public struct ListViewElement
{
   public string Column1 { get; set; }
   public string Column2 { get; set; }
   public string Column3 { get; set; }
   public string Column4 { get; set; }
   public string Column5 { get; set; }
   public string Column6 { get; set; }
   public string Column7 { get; set; }
   public string Column8 { get; set; } //Not for listview 
   public string Column9 { get; set; } //Not for listview
}
public List<ListViewElement> listViewElements;

public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewElement listViewElement1 = new ListViewElement
    {
        Column1 = "Object1",
        Column2 = "APP1",
        Column3 = "File1",
        Column4 = "0.1.4",
        Column5 = "0.1.4",
        Column6 = "Some Information",
        Column7 = "Okay"
    };
   listViewElements.Add(listViewElement1);

   ListViewElement listViewElement2 = new ListViewElement
   {
        Column1 = "Object2",
        Column2 = "App1",
        Column3 = "Var1",
        Column4 = "0.1.4",
        Column5 = "0.1.3",
        Column6 = "Some Information",
        Column7 = "Not Okay"
    };
    listViewElements.Add(listViewElement2);

    ListViewElement listViewElement3 = new ListViewElement
    {
        Column1 = "Object1",
        Column2 = "App1",
        Column3 = "File2",
        Column4 = "0.1.4",
        Column5 = "0.1.3",
        Column6 = "Some Information,
        Column7 = "Not Okay"
    };
    listViewElements.Add(listViewElement3);

    ListViewElement listViewElement4 = new ListViewElement
    {
         Column1 = "Object1",
         Column2 = "App2",
         Column3 = "File2",
         Column4 = "0.1.4",
         Column5 = "0.1.4",
         Column6 = "Some Information,
         Column7 = "Okay"
    };
    listViewElements.Add(listViewElement4);

    foreach(ListViewElement element in listViewElements)
    {
        var row = new { Column1 = element.Column1, Column2 = element.Column2, Column3 = element.Column3, Column4 = element.Column4, Column5 = element.Column5, Column6 = element.Column6, Column7 = .Column7};
        lVTable.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { Content = row, Background = Brushes.White });
    }   }
```

How do I create such ->Filter option box<-

- shown after clicking on column header
- with buttons for:

  - sort ascending / descending
  - select all / specific elements
  - with text field for direct search
- usable for all columns
- Remove after clicking okay
- And attempt his selected methods in listview ?

Comment: Spare your self for the headache and pay some other who already has done those... Try Telerik or Infragistics.

Comment: Or embed excel.